# How to select string that is connected with dot on Emacs

Tags: select, emacs, cursor, cpu-word, expand

I want to select the whole word connected with dot.
Is there any function in Emacs doing this.

Example:

```
123.456.[7]89
```

1. Cursor is on "7".
2. Apply "???function".
3. Region "123.456.789" is selected.

   [123.456.789]

Is there "???function" in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
(defun mark-whole-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((table (syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?. "w" table)
    (with-syntax-table table
      (backward-word)
      (set-mark (point))
      (forward-word))))
```

The key here is modifying the syntax.
So if you replace `?.` with `?-` above, you can mark similarly
`123-456-789`.

Comment: This solved my question. Very tiny code but it works precisely. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I use `expand-region`:

```
(require 'expand-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'er/expand-region)
```

so I press `C-=` once and it selects `789`; I press it a second time and it selects `123.456.789`. It works nice with strings, lines, statements from different languages.

Home: https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el

Install it with ELPA (`M-x list-packages`).

ps: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Elpa

Answer (score 1):

@abo-abo's answer is good.

Just as another data point, you can also use command `thing-region` (from library [`thing-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/thing-cmds.el) -- [Thing-At-Point Commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands)) for this.  It prompts you for a type of *THING* to select.  Just accept the default *THING* type, `sexp`, and you get what you requested in this case.